# STEP File entity documentation

Tags: step

I have a STEP 3D file and when I open through notepad, Its lot of entities and I gone through
 http://www.steptools.com/support/stdev_docs/express/step_irs/html/schema.html#geometry_schema
 but I could not understand the entities. Is there a documentation that explains these entities? If so it would be really helpful to understand.

Answer (score 3):

The [recommended practice for STEP AP 203](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/11728/recprac8.pdf) is a good place to start.

The [CAX-IF recommended practices](http://www.cax-if.org/joint_testing_info.html#recpracs) may also be useful, along with the schemas and file library.

If you need more information, the STEP Module and Resource Library can be purchased from ISO.